# How to get information from selenium?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am doing some test  with Selenium IDE but I want to enter a value and get it after, is it possible ?

I have already tested the command store but it's not what I want...

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to enter a value into a field? or just storing it for future use like a variable? Please elaborate on what exactlly you're trying to do (use case).

Comment: Yes you can. Look at this example where you can then use the variable later in tests:

`<tr>
 <td>storeText</td>
 <td>//h2[@class=&quot;banner-text banner-text--natural&quot;]</td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text and store in a variable:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://cnn.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//h2[@class=&quot;banner-text banner-text--natural&quot;]</td>
    <td>buttonText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${buttonText}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was forgot this option.